# Migrating from Visual C++ 6 to Visual C++ 2008 express

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-c++-2008, visual-c++-2008-express

I'm tring to migrate my code from VCpp 6 to VCpp 2008 express but when I build the solution I receive this error message:

> ```
> icl: warning: problem with
> Microsoft compilation of
> 'c:\Desenvolvimento\DFF\Base\\version.cpp'
> 1>C:\Arquivos de programas\Microsoft
> Visual Studio
> 9.0\VC\include\string.h(69): error:   expected a ";" 1> 
> __DEFINE_CPP_OVERLOAD_STANDARD_FUNC_0_1(char> *,
>  __RETURN_POLICY_DST, __EMPTY_DECLSPEC, _strset, _Inout_z_, 
> char, _Dest, _In_ int, _Value)
> ```

There are a lot of errors like this, sometimes expecting ";", sometimes ")".

Thanks,
Leandro Lima

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was occuring because in the
 Visual C++ 6 I called Intel compiler from 
 a .bat file to create a version number
 for my project. Now I'm using
 Microsoft compiler and I forgot to change the call.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about upgrading to express version if you have need for MFC and the control wizards/editors.  You will not have access to that kind of functionality in Express if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Getting error messages from standard headers usually is a sign of an error in some other error in one of your headers which was included before the standard headers. Have you looked for this?

VC6 is, at least from today's POV, spectacularly bad in supporting standard C++. Among other errors, it accepted a lot of faulty code that isn't accepted by newer versions of VC anymore.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like some variables, types, or preprocessor symbols you need aren't defined.

Check out the code immediately prior to that ";", and then try to track back where it is defined.

Comment: Heh. There ought to be a badge for getting a 0-voted answer accepted. This is like my third time. :-)

Comment: ...out of four. Had it happen again yesterday.